# Fourier transform of electric quadrupole potential

Tags: potential, scattering, fourier-transform, multipole-expansion

I'm struggling to find the scattering amplitude by the first Born approximation (Fourier transform) given by
$$
 f(\vec{k}_f,\vec{k}_i)= -\frac{1}{2\pi}\langle \vec{k}_f | {V}| \vec{k}_i\rangle = -\frac{1}{2\pi}\int d^3r\; e^{-i(\vec{k}_i - \vec{k}_f)\cdot\vec{r}}  
$$
of the electric quadrupole potential as reported in the "Classical Electrodynamics" book by J. D. Jackson:
$$
V = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j} Q_{i,j} \frac{r_i r_j}{r^5}
$$
I started with the element $x^2/r^5$
$$
I = \int d^3r\; e^{-i(\vec{k}_i - \vec{k}_f)\cdot\vec{r}} \frac{x^2}{r^5}
$$
and used spherical coordinates ($x = r \cos \phi \sin \theta$, $d^3r = r^2 \sin \theta d\theta dr d\phi$), with $\vec{q} = \vec{k}_i - \vec{k}_f$ aligned to the $z$ axis:
$$
I = \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\phi \int_{0}^{\pi} d\theta \int_{0}^{\infty} dr\; e^{-iqr \cos\theta} r^2 \sin \theta \frac{(r \cos \phi \sin \theta)^2 }{r^5}
$$
or
$$
I = \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\phi \cos^2 \phi \int_{0}^{\infty} dr \frac{1}{r} \int_{0}^{\pi} d\theta e^{-iqr \cos\theta} \sin^3 \theta
$$
Performing first the integration in $\theta$ and integrating the $\phi$ coordinate, I found:
$$
I = \frac{4\pi}{q^3} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(qr) - qr \cos (qr)}{r^4}
$$
But, the integral above does not converge, which is strange, because this is the interaction, for example, of an incident electron with the quadrupole of a molecule.
Does anyone have some light on this problem?

Comment: You can probably build a simple route for this calculation from the observation that multipole potentials can generally be obtained as derivatives of the Coulomb potential wrt the cartesian coordinates.

Comment: The two terms of the integral seem to be bounded by the integral of $1/r^4$ and $1/r^3$ respectively and so I would assume that they converge.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty do you have a reference for this approach? I haven't found any of them to verify this.

Comment: @SuzuHirose I already tried to integrate, but the problem is in $r = 0$.

Comment: What does "I started with the element $x^2/r^5$" signify? Also why is $\vec{q}$ confined to the $z$ axis?

Comment: @SuzuHirose $x^2/r^5$ is the element where $i = j = 1$, i.e., $r_i = r_j = x$ in the potential. I chose $\vec{q}$ aligned to the $z$ axis for convenience.

Comment: I tried to follow this derivation but I'm not sure it's on the right course. Unfortunately the calculation is one I'm not very familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be best to heed the advice by Emilio Pisanty. You have to be careful about the conventions for FT you are using, all the imaginary units, signs, factors etc., but this should be super-easy in cartesian coordinates.

Just a sketch:
The Poisson equation is solved by the $1/r$ potential
$$
-\Delta \varphi = \delta \quad \Rightarrow \quad \varphi = \frac{1}{4\pi r}
$$
which after Fourier Transform corresponds to
$$
k^2 \widehat{\varphi} = 1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \widehat{\varphi} = \frac{1}{k^2}\,.
$$

Now, make use of the rule $\widehat{\partial_j f} = i k_j \widehat{f}$ (factors depending on conventions for FT, pick you favourite exercise book and follow theirs or the one given by your assignment) and understand that the quadrupole potential is
$$
V = Q_{ij} \partial_i \partial_j \varphi
$$
wherein $\varphi$ is the point charge potential from above. We thus easily find that
$$
\widehat{V}=-Q_{ij} k_i k_j \widehat{\varphi} = - Q_{ij} \frac{k_i k_j}{k^2}\,.
$$

Beware that somewhere in this calculation there is also contained a delta-term in the quadrupole potential because
$$
\partial_i \partial_j \varphi = - \frac{1}{3} \delta_{ij} \delta + \frac{3 x_i x_j - r^2 \delta_{ij}}{4 \pi r^5}
$$
(and you might have to develop an interest in distributions and spherical regularization etc. which can be quite technical and maybe make more difficult what above looks like an easy calculation).

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you very much!